# Any function in Oracle similar to COALESCE, but instead of NULL works on ERRORs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I need to convert a numeric column value into time. It's a 6 digit field, but unfortunately, different processes over the years inserted data in different format, some HHMM, and others HHMMSS. Let's call this column colTime. I use colTime in combination with another 8 digits numeric field which contains a date in YYYYMMDD format, let's call this colDate.

It is being used as below to construct a TIMESTAMP in UTC zone:

```
select TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(NULLIF(colDate,0), LPAD(NULLIF(colTime,0),4,0)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZR') from tab1;
```

The problem here obviously is that the colTime may contain 4 OR 6 digit data so I cannot know the correct LPAD number in advance. When the above statement encounters a 6 digit field it throws an error.

I was thinking if I have a function similar to COALESCE that can execute the second argument if the first one returns an error then I'd be able to accommodate LPAD 4 and 6 cases.

I can use a CASE statement, but was hoping for something more graceful.

Comment: And... that's why you store data as the correct datatype. Even if you assume you only have HHMM or HHMMSS to deal with (and who knows what else could have been out in there over the years), if you have a value of 1, how are you supposed to guess whether that is 00:01 or 00:00:01? Are you planning to prioritise one possible format over the other?

Comment: @AlexPoole priority will be 00:01. By prioritizing 4 digits, if we still run into issues (e.g. for some reason we have 6045 which is invalid HHMM), we just want to ignore the actual value and assume 12:00. This is unfortunately a legacy system that we inherited with polluted data, trying to make as much sense as we can with these assumptions.

Comment: While a longer value will fail conversion, you may use a longer date format for both 4 and 6 digits: `select
  to_date(
    '2021-12-31 01:23',
    'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
  ) as d
from dual`. For completely invalid values like `6543` there's an answer below with `on conversion error`

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `COALESCE` if you also use the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` syntax in `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```
select
    coalesce
    (
        to_timestamp('2021-01-01' || ' ' ||the_time default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD HHMI'),
        to_timestamp('2021-01-01' || ' ' ||the_time default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD HHMISS')
    )
from
(
    select '0102'   the_time from dual union all
    select '010203' the_time from dual
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @jon-heller! Unfortunately, we are on Oracle 12 where `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find out which format the data comes from and then you can convert it appropriately.

For example:

```
with
d (col_time) as (
  select '0215' from dual
  union all select '183207' from dual
  union all select '12:34:56' from dual
  union all select 'really-bad-data' from dual
)
select d.*,
  case when regexp_like(col_time, '^[0-9]{4}$') then 'Short Time Format'
       when regexp_like(col_time, '^[0-9]{6}$') then 'Long Time Format'
       else 'Other Time Format'
  end as guessed_format
from d;
```

Result:

```
 COL_TIME         GUESSED_FORMAT    
 ---------------- ----------------- 
 0215             Short Time Format 
 183207           Long Time Format  
 12:34:56         Other Time Format 
 really-bad-data  Other Time Format
```

Comment: Wouldn't using >9999 or <9999 with ELSE be simpler?

Comment: @PratP. Yes, in your case you are converting from a numeric value, so your solution is simpler. If you had a character column, this solution could cover more cases.